# Need some help in deleting the data from list and again append it in same list

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have developed a Django app where user can upload multiple files. I can upload all the multiple files and its paths in the form of a list separated by comma(,) in MySql database.For example I have uploaded three files

1. Logging a Defect.docx,
   2.Mocks (1).pptx and 
   3.Mocksv2.pptx

and it gets stored in database as following( Converting the individual file path into list and joining all the paths results in following form) :

```
FileStore/client/Logging a Defect.docx,FileStore/client/Mocks (1).pptx,FileStore/client/Mocksv2.pptx,
```

Now I need help while deleting particular file. For example when I'm deleting Logging a Defect.docx then I should be deleting first element of list alone and retain the other two paths. I'll be sending only name of document.

I'm retrieving the path as list and then I have to check if the name of doc being passed is there in each element of the list and if it matches then I should delete that element keeping the other elements intact. How to approach this ? It sounds like more of python question than Django question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list-expression to filter the splitted text, and rebuild the string using join function

```
>>> db_path = 'FileStore/client/Logging a Defect.docx,FileStore/client/Mocks (1).pptx,FileStore/client/Mocksv2.pptx'
>>> file_to_delete = 'Logging a Defect.docx'
>>> file_separator = ","
>>> new_db_path = [
...     path.strip()
...     for path in db_path.split(file_separator)
...     if path.strip() and file_to_delete not in path
... ]
>>> string_to_save = file_separator.join(new_db_path)
>>> string_to_save
'FileStore/client/Mocks (1).pptx,FileStore/client/Mocksv2.pptx'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the text in your database and then use `remove` method of the list in python and then write back the new value into databse:

```
text = "FileStore/client/Logging a Defect.docx,FileStore/client/Mocks (1).pptx,FileStore/client/Mocksv2.pptx,"
splitted = text.split(',')
#filename is the one you want to delete
entry = "FileStore/client/{filename}".format(filename="Mocks (1).pptx")
if entry in splitted:
    splitted.remove(entry)

newtext = ""
for s in splitted:
    newtext += s
    newtext += ','
```

now write back newtext to database

Answer (score 0):

Not boasting or anything but I came up with my own logic for my question. It looks far less complicated but it works fine.

```
                db_path = 'FileStore/client/Logging a Defect.docx,FileStore/client/Mocks (1).pptx,FileStore/client/Mocksv2.pptx'
                path_list = db_path.split(",")
                doc = 'Logging a Defect.docx'
                for i in path_list :
                    if doc in i:
                        y.remove("FileStore/"+client+"/"+doc)
                new_path =  ",".join(y)
                print new_path
```